# Get data from SharePoint Folder using Power BI

Tags: sharepoint-online, odata, powerbi

Can I show image and meta data details from SharePoint online asset library in PowerBI report,

I tried to use SharePoint Folder as data connection but I got this error :

> Unable to connect : SharePoint Request failed: OData Version : 3 and 4
>   error : the remote server returned an error : (404) Not Found

Is there any other method to get data from library , what about OData feed option ?

I appreciate your support

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding error message : **the remote server returned an error : (404) Not Found**

- Make sure that the provided URL is the site URL and not list URL.

For more details check [OData Connection Errors](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Integrations-with-Files-and/OData-Connection-Errors-Solution/td-p/27794)

Regarding **Is there any other method to get data from library , what about OData feed option?**

Yes you can use OData feed to get a data from a library as the following

- Open Power BI > From the above ribbon > Click on Get Data > OData Feed.
- Set the Url to `https://rootsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc`.
- Set the credential to windows authentication , it's not worked with anonymous authontication.
- Now it's should connected.
- Select your library that you need to retrieve its data .
- Click Load, now it's should be loaded properly !

Comment: thank you for your help, in step 2, i tried to set the the url but give unable to connect

Comment: I am sorry the URL was wrong , I updated my answer , please check it